Snowflake Proc call with Param
So I have a SP per below and if I'm to make a proc call in JAN-2025 (I will need data for 2024-DEC ) . But current logic would not support that , as per below line
MONTH(to_date('2025-01-02') )-1 

I would get month of zero; and there that results in empty data set. Hence the Union.
Now when i exec the below proc I get error
"SQL compilation error: syntax error line 12 at position 0 unexpected 'select'. syntax error line 20 at position 4 unexpected 'as'."

Prod def :
CALL SP_1_test(
     select top 1 FISCAL_YEAR from (
    select FISCAL_YEAR
from  tmp_cal
         where FISCAL_PERIOD >= 1 and FISCAL_YEAR = YEAR(to_date('2025-01-02') ) 
         and FISCAL_PERIOD = MONTH(to_date('2025-01-02') )-1 
           and FISCAL_PERIOD_WEEK = 1 and FISCAL_PERIOD_DAY = 1
           Union all 
select    year(to_date(to_date('2025-01-02')))-1     as    FISCAL_YEAR
 ) as a /*this is param 1 valued as fiscal year 2020, 2021, etc.*/
,
select top 1 FISCAL_PERIOD from ( 
select FISCAL_PERIOD
from  tmp_cal
         where FISCAL_PERIOD >= 1 and FISCAL_YEAR = YEAR(to_date('2025-01-02') ) 
         and FISCAL_PERIOD = MONTH(to_date('2025-01-02') )-1 
           and FISCAL_PERIOD_WEEK = 1 and FISCAL_PERIOD_DAY = 1
                      union all 
select 12 as FISCAL_PERIOD         
)   as a /*this is param 2. A month valued between 1 to 12 */
           
           )

Question is : can I not do named queries like above to pass my variable's in underlaying proc?
If not what is an alternate solution.
Thanks.

Hi - I'm not sure I understand your question or what you are trying to do. When you call the SP do you always want it to return data for the previous month (in which case why do you need to pass anything into it as parameters) or do you pass in a date and the SP calculates the result for the month previous to that date - or are you doing something else?
Please can you also update your question with an example of what your SP is currently expecting as input parameter(s) e.g. CALL SP_1_test('2024-01-01') and what the datatype(s) of the input parameter(s) are? Thanks

So the SP expected 2 int params : Param 1 for year, Param 2 for month (both numbers) . There is a small curve ball - cannot be calendar month. But company calendar ;  which closes on last sat of each month.  I did not want to deal with that hassle, so I join back to my calendar table & get starting of each "current month" and -1 off it; to get data for "previous month" that bizz needs to do their reporting off of.

Wouldn't you just pass through the date to the SP as a parameter and then in the SP take a month off that date (ADD_MONTHS) and using the resulting date to get the min/max dates for your report from your company calendar table?
